# Belle icon shape in CSS

Tags: css, icons, css-shapes

How can I draw this Belle icon shape in CSS only?

[image]

I've tried the border-radius on a square element but not getting the exact corners.

Comment: Check this link, you can create `http://www.cssmatic.com/border-radius`

Comment: "I've tried the border-radius on a square element but not getting the exact corners." can we see that please?

Comment: @web-tiki border-radius: 40% and similar values. Thisi is what I tried

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, in order to achieve the exact effect, we cannot rely on a single element even if we use percentage on `border-radius`.

So one option could be using two (pseudo-)elements overlapping each other where one of them is rotated by `90deg`:

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  
  /* Just for demo */
  width: 95vmin; height: 95vmin;
  
  position: relative;
}

div:after, div:before {
  content: "";
  background: teal;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 8%;
  right: 8%;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 50% / 22%;
}

div:before {
  transform: rotate(-90deg); /* vendor prefixes omitted due to brevity */
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: This is a much better example

Answer (score 4):

If you want the exact shape, you'd be better off using SVG. See for example :

```html
<svg version="1.1" height="200" width="200" viewBox="0 0 30 30">
  <path d="M15 0 Q0 0 0 15 T15 30 30 15 15 0" fill="#249B57" stroke="none" />
</svg>
```

This uses a path with Quadratic beziers (Q)

Answer (score 2):

Use a border radius with a percentage (`%`) unit, rather than a `px` unit:

```css
div{
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  background:tomato;
  border-radius: 45%;
  }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

**NOTE**

It is safe to say, however, I have only tried to replicate the image depicted in the question, and so may not conform to a shape of a 'belle' in which you have referred to (in which I used to think was a disney character, who would be much harder to replicate in css).

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle,
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/n9z5D/1142/)

```
.belly{
    background: #2AA55F;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 82px / 83px;
}
```